# TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

Setting up a login/signup page for a grocery store app and I continue to get this error.

"TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment"

This happens whenever I try to run the server and refresh the login page so I can see if it works.

***Example code: (this is from my manage.py file)***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='groceryshop.settings'
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***Example Code: settings.py (terminal continues to say my apps are uninstalled)***

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

from userprofile.models import UserProfile
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-pw7g8*-80b!900@na(cjpgp21nr784-0aawklg8!br#cel2!@h'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'userprofile',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

]
```

ty for any/all help. <3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `os.environ.setdefault['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='groceryshop.settings'`, what do you expect that to mean? In particular: what do you expect to be the type of `os.environ`, and what do you expect `.setdefault` to mean/do?

Answer (score 2):

This line is incorrect because `os.environ.setdefault` is a method, but you're trying to use it like a dict-like object.

```
os.environ.setdefault['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='groceryshop.settings'
```

Instead, you should be doing this:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'groceryshop.settings')
```

And for your reference, a documentation link for [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

Comment: ok cool, I got 'ModuleErrorNotFound: no module named 'userprofile'       pls assist <3

Comment: @bobsmiths Have you made sure your path to the app/module is correct? Does it contain an `AppConfig`?

Comment: idk if path is correct, but I do have appconfig. looks like this: from django.apps import AppConfig


    class UserprofileConfig(AppConfig):
        default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
        name = 'userprofile'

Comment: @bobsmiths Might want to post a follow-up question since I'm not really a Django user anymore, but I think your app would be called `userprofile.UserprofileConfig`.

Comment: ok ty. will post another question soon ty.